# Map network drive to computer

Tags: windows, mapped-drive

I have a nas - with like 20 shares on it, for various good reasons.  On my main desktop though, I often do maintenance and things, move stuff around especially with scripts - and it just makes it easier if I can map it, so CD to it.   But I can't figure out how to do it.

I can map all the original shares - eg \\10.0.0.11\photos or \\10.0.0.11\backup  - but what I want is just to map \\10.0.0.11 to a drive, but i can't figure out how - if I do

```
net use w: \\10.0.0.11
```

I just get

```
System error 67 has occurred.

The network name cannot be found.
```

is there any way to force it?   I know I can make a fake share that symlinks to the others, on the NAS - but I run into this problem a lot and would like to know how to fix it

Comment: Add \foldername to your network string

Comment: You can assign a name to your drive and make sure it is shared to you. Then \drivename will work. I use this.

Comment: the entire point is _not_ to add \foldername to the string - yes that works fine, but doesn't help me

what do you m mean "assign a name to my drive"?

Comment: Yes. I can name my drive and share it. That aids folder mapping

Answer (score 1):

First option: Enter \\10.0.0.11 in the File Explorer address bar. It's not a permanent mapping, but it should give you quick access to all shares.

Second option: In the NAS interface, where you create shares, see if there is an option such as "Share an entire storage" (that's what I have on my Linksys router). Click that and give it a name, such as "root". You can then map a drive letter to that share to access everything.